# Hosted service for queuing and running tasks in parallel in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency, async-await, asp.net-core

I am attempting to construct a background service for an IIS-hosted ASP.NET Core project that basically queues tasks and runs them, and I decided to go with the `IHostedService` interface in Core 2.1 because of [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks). The tutorial does describe the case of running tasks *one-by-one* and in the order received, very well, and it does suffice for my purposes, but I was wondering whether it would be possible to run tasks *in parallel* via the same implementation of a `BackgroundService`, in such a way that one may control the maximum number of tasks running concurrently.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349826/parallel-queued-background-tasks-with-hosted-services-in-asp-net-core) on SO, but was unable to get the proposed solution to work for the following task creation loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   var j = i;
   await _queue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async token =>
   {
       int s = j % 2 == 0 ? 5 : 1;
       Thread.Sleep(s * 1000);
       Debug.WriteLine("Processed " + j + " in " + s + " seconds");
   }
}
```

where `_queue` is the `IBackgroundTaskQueue` defined in the tutorial. Indeed, for the `SemaphoreSlim` in the solution, but with the `initialCount` setting set to 4, I still receive the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. in order.

I then tried to implement my own version of the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` and `DequeueAsync` methods as an implemenation of `IBackgroundTaskQueue` called `NewMultiThreadBackgroundTaskQueue`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueueSystem.Queue
{
    public class NewMultiThreadBackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> _workItems =
            new ConcurrentQueue<Func<CancellationToken, Task>>();

        private readonly List<Task> _runItems = new List<Task>();

        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _signal;
        private const int InitialCount = 4;

        public NewMultiThreadBackgroundTaskQueue()
        {
            _signal = new SemaphoreSlim(InitialCount);
        }

        public Task QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
        {
            if (workItem == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
            }

            _workItems.Enqueue(async token =>
            {
                await _signal.WaitAsync(token);
                try
                {
                    await workItem(token);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _signal.Release();
                }
            });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            while (!_workItems.IsEmpty && _runItems.Count < InitialCount)
            {
                _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
                if (workItem != null)
                {
                    _runItems.Add(Task.Run(async () => await workItem(cancellationToken), cancellationToken));
                }
            }

            if (!_runItems.Any()) return async token => await Task.CompletedTask;

            var completed = await Task.WhenAny(_runItems);
            _runItems.Remove(completed);
            return async token => await completed;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the `DequeueAsync` method in a `QueueHostedService` just as in the mentioned tutorial (i.e., nothing has changed):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using QueueSystem.Queue;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace QueueSystem.Services
{
    public class QueueHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public QueueHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            TaskQueue = taskQueue;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<QueueHostedService>();
        }

        public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is starting.");


            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

                try
                { 
                    await workItem(cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex,
                        "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
                }
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");
        }
    }

}
```

The `DequeueAsync` method does work as intended in the above background service, but I fear that I'm not using the `CancellationToken` correctly and my usage of `Task.CompletedTask` is a bit on the frivolous side.

**EDIT:**

Following [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233597/hosted-service-for-queuing-and-running-tasks-in-parallel-in-asp-net-core#comment503261_233597), I have changed the content of the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` and `DequeueAsync` methods:

```
public void QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task> workItem)
{
    if (workItem == null)
    {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
    }
    _workItems.Enqueue(workItem);
}

public async Task<Func<CancellationToken, Task>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_workItems.IsEmpty) return async token => await Task.CompletedTask;

    var removed = _runItems.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
    while (!_workItems.IsEmpty && _runItems.Count < InitialCount)
    {
        _workItems.TryDequeue(out var workItem);
        if (workItem != null)
        {
            _runItems.Add(Task.Run(() => workItem(cancellationToken), cancellationToken));
        }
    }
    return async token => await Task.WhenAny(_runItems);
}
```

This still works (it dequeues and runs at most `InitialCount` tasks in parallel), but I'm still curious if there are any obvious improvements that I'm missing.

Comment: Hi! The code is working as intended and tasks are executed in parallel, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: For anyone in the Close Queue, the author believes the code is working as intended, do not close for that reason.

Comment: `_workItems.Enqueue(async token =>
            {
                await _signal.WaitAsync(token);
                try
                {
                    await workItem(token);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _signal.Release();
                }
            });`why? why this is this being done... not even sure what its about. surely it should take a task and thats it? the rest is handled by the dequeue, could you explain this

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It might work without the SemaphoreSlim, but I don't know for sure. I guess it probably will due to the SemaphoreSlim-free handling of the dequeueing of tasks (which means that I see what you see). I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: You are correct - SemaphoreSlim is irrelevant. Also, I figured it would be nicer to check if the ConcurrentQueue is empty in the beginning of the `DequeueAsync` method and return a completed task if it is - then remove all completed tasks at the start of the while loop and return the `Task.WhenAny(_runItems)` after the while loop. That looks much better. Thanks for the feedback!